# Does QNetworkAccessManager support HTTPS proxy?

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

[I compiled OpenSSL on my Windows machine](https://developernote.com/2020/06/compiling-qt5-15-0-with-openssl-support-with-msvc2017-on-windows/) and was able to do HTTPS queries with `QNetworkAccessManager`, but when I try to add HTTPS proxy

```
QNetworkAccessManager m_nm;
connect(&m_nm, &QNetworkAccessManager::proxyAuthenticationRequired, this, &BinanceReceiver::onProxyAuthenticationRequired);
connect(&m_nm, &QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors, this, &BinanceReceiver::onSslErrors);

QNetworkProxy m_proxy(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy, "host.com", 3129, "user", "password");
m_nm.setProxy(m_proxy);

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(MakeUrl(url));
QNetworkReply* reply = m_nm.get(request);

QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [this, reply]()
{
    if (reply->error())
    {
        netLogger.error(reply->errorString());
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }

    //Ensure it is deleted after this handler is called, but not before.
    delete reply;
});
```

it stops working, I do not get the reply at all and neither `proxyAuthenticationRequired` nore `sslErrors` is triggered.

It is a Squid HTTPS proxy with the authentication.

Does `QNetworkAccessManager` support HTTPS proxy?

Comment: Is SSL support enabled for your Qt build?

Comment: @Pie_Jesu yes it is